# Create a word and pdf documents form an html, maintaining the format

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have an html document that I created using syncfution, but what I wantt to do, is to share this document as word or pdf but mantaning the format (Bullets, color, etc).

I also tried to use syncfution to make the convertion, but it dosent work

For example I manage to upload it to Azure in word format, but the formating, and styles are gone

```
 private async void ShareOptionsAction() {

        var share = DependencyService.Get<IShare>();
        var localFolder = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;

            string fileName = $"{NoteName}.docx";

            var filePath = Path.Combine(localFolder, fileName);

            using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument()) {
                //Loads or opens an existing Word document from stream
                Stream inputStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(HtmlText);
                //Loads or opens an existing Word document through Open method of WordDocument class
                document.Open(inputStream, FormatType.Html);
                //Creates an instance of memory stream
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
                    //Saves the Word document to file stream.
                    document.Save(fileStream, FormatType.Docx);
                }
                //Closes the document
                document.Close();
            }

            await App.AzureService.UploadToAzureBlobStorage(filePath, fileName);
```

This will convert it fine, but I loose all the formatng
is there any way to do this with a third party? and maintain the formatting

Comment: the title of your question doesn't seem to have any relation to the question you actually asked

Comment: @Jaso you are right, thank you for pointing it out, and not giving me negative point like almost everyone in stakoverflow

Comment: @KJ forget about the shre part or pdf, I just want to convert a HTML to Word maintainting the format I have on my html.

Comment: You can check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de805fc9-ad5f-43a4-b3f3-a895ff18c134/support-to-convert-the-html-to-pdf-in-xamarin-forms?forum=xamarinforms) which used the webview to convert the html to a pdf.